# Jpeg files defect and extremely huge after file transfer to laptop

Tags: data-recovery, mtp, xiaomi-mi-10t-pro

I have Cut&Paste some .jpg files from my mobile phone (internal storage) to my laptop (file transfer by cable), now those files are ¡¡5gb!! each instead of 5MB and I can´t watch the pics. Pics folder size is about 3TB, while my SSD is 0.5TB, so that´s ridiculous.

Mobile phone is Xiaomi Mi 10T Pro, Android 12, MIUI global 13.0.8. Laptop is Lenovo with Windows 10.

Any idea how to get my pics back?

Comment: MTP protocol used for file transfer is known to be slow and unreliable. Furthermore there were some bugs when moving files, they should already be resolved but as you have noticed there are other potential problems that cause data loss. You can try to tuna photo recovery software like photorec on the large files you have. Hopefully photorec finds the original image(s).

Comment: If you have some technical skill you can use [adb to pull files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63589399/295004) which is what I had to do when I had more photos than what Android File Transfer using MTP could show.