# Can a user recover photos deleted from DCIM/Camera in Android files via USB-linked file move to Windows 10?

Tags: data-recovery, photos, mtp

Yesterday, I connected my phone to my Windows 10 PC, and transferred all of my camera photos to a new Windows folder via Windows Explorer using the 'Move' function. I have since learned this was a bad move.

All of the files appeared to have moved to the new folder, and I was able to open them on my PC with no problem.

That is, until I unplugged my phone from the PC.

Each of the .jpg files are registering as being comically large ie.

> Size: 8.7 GB
>
> Size on Disk: 8.00 KB

Additionally, they all have the shortcut icons:
[image]

I have tried some of those scammy-looking recovery tools that scan for images, but they only pull things that are stored in app caches such as telegram, Facebook, text messages, etc. but not any of the approximately 1,200 photos transferred.  Some of those software packages appear to have additional functionality that could be used if my phone were rooted.

I have already checked cloud recovery and backup options such as android recovery tools in settings, google photos, clouds, trash bins in photos and file manager etc.

Windows appears to have, at the least, wiped the reference of the data from the phone completely when it moved, and the files stored on the PC now open as corrupted files.

**1) Would this type of transfer have destroyed the binary data, or only have removed the reference?**

**2) Would rooting my phone now be the only plausible way to now partially recover this data?**

**3) Additionally, is it likely that anything about the data moved to my PC is useable or recoverable on the PC rather than attacking this issue via the phone?**

Comment: Rooting your phone is not an option as it will erase all data in a way that makes all data  unrecoverable. MTP is known to be slow and unstable, especially the move operation. The size of the JPEG image in your screen shot is shown as 8.70 GB which reminds me on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248309/2241).

Comment: Try that (outdated) free tool directly on MicroSD Card with Card Reader on PC, it will recover files from FAT file system [ZAR Zero Assumption Recovery](https://www.z-a-recovery.com)